# Can electromagnetism be used to generate gravity?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

The electromagnetic field produces a gravitational field because the EM field tensor produces a stress energy which in turn produces a gravitational field via the Einstein field equations.

This would seem to imply that a particular arrangement of current and voltage could be used to generate an electromagnetic field configuration which would in turn produce gravity on demand.

Is this actually possible?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, because your question already states that an electromagnetic field can produce a gravitational field. Perhaps you are asking, Is this method feasible? That would be an engineering question. Or perhaps you are asking, Is it possible to turn gravity on/off by flipping a switch in an electrical circuit?

Comment: I think his question is not that ambiguous and would correspond to the latter case @sammygerbil.  I do not know why he formulated the title question though.

Comment: Note that all stress-energy produces gravity (including stress-energy arising from the EM field). But the energy to produce the EM field had to come from somewhere, so it's not like the EM field is generating gravity "out of nothing". Having a switch that turns on and off an EM field "produces gravity" in the same sense as you waving your hand around "produces gravity" (due to your hand having more energy when you wave it around).

Comment: @enumaris Does your hand have more energy when you wave it around? It has more kinetic energy, but where did that come from?

Comment: @sammygerbil yes that was my point, the energy to wave my hand around had to come from somewhere...just like the energy to create an EM field has to come from somewhere. So it's not really a "switch on/switch off" kind of thing.

Comment: A tiny bit of the mass of the proton comes from this. So yes, it is possible, and even realized in Nature already. However, energy conservation prevents you from turning this on and off by demand. You may convert the energy stored in the electromagnetic field to another form, but this other form will gravitate as much, and you won't be able to "switch gravity on and off" that way.

Comment: if your static electric field is on the order of $m_e^2c^3/e\hbar$ you will produce $e^+e^-$  pairs, which will screen the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are asking if a gravitational field can be switched on/off by flipping a switch in an electrical circuit, I think the answer is No.

The electromagnetic energy which you create must come from some other form of energy, which also gravitates. You are merely exchanging one source of gravity for another. At best you are moving the gravitational field from one place to another, in a finite time, like moving a mass.

*A particular arrangement of current and voltage* is not necessary. Any form of energy is sufficient to do the job.

Nothing feasible could be done by this method which could not be done more efficiently by bringing a mass to the required location. Even matching the feeble gravitational field of a 1kg mass would require an energy of $9\times 10^{16}$J, which is approximately the UK energy consumption for one month.

Comment: So the answer is that, for example, a sufficiently heavy current in an inductor would then produce a sufficiently large magnetic field in space nearby, which would represent enough stored energy in that volume to produce local curvature in spacetime which gets expressed as gravity- but the quantity of magnetic field energy needed to make a measurable amount of gravity by this method is so large as to be essentially impossible. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: OK got it, I'll go off now and do some algebra and I might be back with another question. Thanks for your answer- NN

Comment: @niels The Google Calculator is handy for stuff like this because it understands a large number of units, and several useful constants. You can access it via the search bar. Eg, `(1g*c^2)/(3MW)` returns 346.741967 days. So it takes almost 347 days of the energy from a 3 megawatt generator to get 1 gram's worth of electricity.

Comment: that is coool. -NN

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just as you say, the EM field tensor produces a stress-energy, which is the source of gravitational effects.

A charged black hole does have a different gravitational field then a non-charged one.

Now you are asking whether this can be used for creating a gravitational field. Yes it is possible, but if you check the EM field tensor, and the stress-energy it creates, then you will realize that to create a certain amount of (usable) stress-energy that can be used technologically (as a source of gravity), you would need to use so much EM charge, so much energy, that will not be effective.

Comment: What's the order of magnitude charge you need to make 1 g? I can compute the curvature of the metric near 1 Coulomb of charge, but how do you estimate the gravitational force?

Comment: @RyanThorngren The gravitational potential directly relates to the gravitational time dilation. If you can compute the curvature, you would know the time dilation and therefore the gravitational potential and the gravitational force. None of this is practical until gravity becomes stronger than electromagnetism, meaning a black hole. In any other case charges would just fly apart with nothing strong enough to keep them together.

Comment: But how do I get $m/s^2$ from $1/m^2$? Forgive the naive question. I know acceleration is reference-frame-dependent.

Comment: @RyanThorngren  Please use @ to notify of your replies (no spaces). Gravitational acceleration $g$ is a derivative of potential $\Phi$ over distance $r$ in the direction of motion $g=-\dfrac{d\Phi}{dr}$. Almost everything is reference frame dependent, even mass, so you must use all variables from the same reference frame. - http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/gpot.html

Answer (score -5):

Sort of. there are four fundamental forces of nature. These forces interact.
Like a pair of gears. with EM being 1x10^39th power stronger than gravity. EM is a rather "huge" gear, and gravity is very small. If the correct interaction can be applied conversion with the ratio here (1x10^39th power) would result in VERY impressive results.